# Call python function in C code

Tags: python, c, cython

i written small code like addition for two numbers in python.

```
addition.py
  def add(a,b):
       c=a+b
       print "result is...",c


mainpgm.c
 ???
```

how to call the addition.py/add function in the C(mainpgm) program.

Already i saw some links but i am not to getting clear.

Any suggestions to call the function in c.

Comment: If looking at _some links_ didn't make it clear, chances are that posted a question won't either.

Comment: There isn't any Cython here, is there ?

Comment: Why do you want to call this from a C program? Can you give more context? Is the C program embedding a Python interpreter? Is there some large external utility written in Python you want to invoke from C?

Comment: @user2357112 i am calling some python function which doing database operations like select, insert in table. now that python code have to call inside the some c program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading [the Python manual](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#very-high-level-embedding),

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("import addition\naddition.add(42, 42)\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

might do what you want.

Comment: In technical terms, what you do is "embedding Python interpreter into C/C++". Here the doc page: http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/index.html

Comment: @AKX facing the following error when compiling... " undefined reference to `Py_SetProgramName'"......undefined reference to `Py_Finalize'"

Comment: You'll need to link against the Python library. (How this is done depends on your environment, but for gcc, `-lpython` might work.)

Comment: @AKX is it possible to send parameters from command line.????