# Pass argument to PyRun_File(***)

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am writing some code in C and in Python.

I have a python file called `sample.py` which accepts two string parameters.

My C program calls the python function using the `PyRun_SimpleString()`. In this way I am not able to pass any parameters.

By `PyRun_SimpleString()`:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
 ......
PyRun_SimpleString("import sample\nsample.mainfunc("argv[1]",'Isolated_domU_t')\n");
.....
}
```

How can I pass parameters `argv[1]` by using `PyRun_SimpleString(*)`?

Comment: If you want to call a function why are you executing a program instead? You should import the `sample` module and call the function using `PyObject_Call*` functions.

Comment: It looks like you don't know how to concatenate strings in C. Please have a look at the following SO question on that matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/c-string-concatenation

Answer (score 1):

To set arguments do like the following code:

```cpp
wchar_t** wargv = new wchar_t*[argc];
for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
    wargv[i] = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[i], nullptr);
    if(wargv[i] == nullptr)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}

Py_Initialize();

// char* py=...
PySys_SetArgv(argc, wargv);
PyRun_SimpleString(py);

Py_Finalize();

for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
    PyMem_RawFree(wargv[i]);
    wargv[i] = nullptr;
}

delete[] wargv;
wargv = nullptr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`PyRun_String`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/veryhigh.html#PyRun_String). It has a signature similar to `PyRun_File`:

```
PyObject* PyRun_String(const char *str, int start, PyObject *globals, PyObject *locals)
```

**Update:**

In your case, it whould be simple enough to just copy the command line arguments into the string you want to execute, just like you tried in your question. Your code won't work though, because that's not how you concatenate strings in C. Try this instead:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char py[1000]; /* that should be big enough */
    strcpy(py, "import sample\nsample.mainfunc(");
    strcat(py, argv[1]);
    strcat(py, ",'Isolated_domU_t')\n");

    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString(py);
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

This is, of course, only the quick&dirty version without checking if there even is an argument passed to the program, or checking for its length.

Comment: i am not getting(understood) this syntax so only i posted here. where can i get the real examples..:)

Comment: The syntax is almost the same as `PyRun_File`'s. I thought you wanted a method that takes parameters similar to `PyRun_File`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300349/call-python-function-in-c-code please refer this one. in that answer i changed the main to addfunction() and for that addfunction()[main] i am passing the parameters how i am can achieve that one. simply in that answer it as 42,42 instaed of that one i have to pass from command line

Comment: It looks like what you want is to take arguments that you pass to your C program and pass them to your embedded python script. If that is the case, please update your question accordingly. I'll update my answer later.

Answer (score 0):

can use the snprintf or like his function
and  type this

```
char haies1[2048];
snprintf(haies1, sizeof(haies1),"import sample\n"
                "sample.mainfunc("%s",'Isolated_domU_t')\n",argv[1])
```

then can use the PyRun_SimpleString function like this

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString(haies1);
Py_Finalize();
```